# Cannot figure out why door won't open

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey guys I’m having a problem with my code which I can’t figure out, I’m trying to make it so when the player collides with the door or touches it that it plays the animation. Problem is the animation won’t play at all.

Also keep in mind that the door script is attached to the door.

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class DoorOpen : MonoBehaviour
{

    //this variable will decide wether door is open or not, its initially on false because the door is closed.

    bool isDoorOpen = false;

    //this variable will play the audio when the door opens
    public AudioSource sound01;

    void Start()
    {

    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Bathroom_Door" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            GetComponent<Animation>().Play("DoorO");
            sound01.Play();
            //this variable becomes true because the door is open
            isDoorOpen = true;
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Shure it's `DoorO` ? Did you mean `Door0` ?

Comment: Yeah I checked it. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: The way it is set up now you must press the F key in the same frame the OnCollisionEnter event is generated and thus the door does not always open.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the GetKeyDown in the update and open the door if the player entered in the collision box. An other option would be to use the [OnCollisionStay](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay.html) in stead of the OnCollisionEnter because the OnCollisionEnter is only called once on the start of the collision.

```
public class DoorOpen : MonoBehaviour
{

//this variable will decide wether door is open or not, its initially on false because the door is closed.

bool isDoorOpen = false;
bool canOpenDoor = false;

//this variable will play the audio when the door opens
public AudioSource sound01;

void Start()
{

}
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Bathroom_Door")
    {
         canOpenDoor = true;
    }
}
void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Bathroom_Door")
    {
         canOpenDoor = false;
    }
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
     if (canOpenDoor && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("DoorO");
        sound01.Play();
        //this variable becomes true because the door is open
        isDoorOpen = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hey I want to say thanks a bunch for reconstructing my code and taking the effort to edit it. Though it didn't work the door didn't open I attatched the script to the main camera,first person controller, and the door it self. Do I need a rigid body or something?

Comment: the script should be attached on the door and the door should have a collider on it for the OnCollision to trigger. What you will need to do with the OnCollision is run against the collider for it to trigger. To solve this you would need to use the OnTrigger methods and use a collider which is set to trigger.

Comment: Ok so under the OnCollisionExit I added a new function : void OnTriggerEnter(Collision col)
 {
  if (col.gameObject.name == "Pool_Room_Door")
  {
   canOpenDoor = true;
  }
 }   but didn't work.

Comment: Ok so I just edited my code it said that OnTriggerEnter can't have the Collision parameter has to be collider I changed that, so now it looks like this void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
 {
  if (col.gameObject.name == "Pool_Room_Door")
  {
   canOpenDoor = true;
  }
 }  Also are you sure I don't need to add the script on main camera or first person controller?

Comment: Sorry for 100 comments I changed from the bathroom door cause I had problems with it I'm using another door called "Pool_Room_Door"

Comment: I'm sure the script should be attached to the door trigger or collider object, depending on if you use the onTrigger or onCollision. Further more you can try removing `canOpenDoor` in the update and see if you can open the door. That should be possible anywhere you stands. You can also try to add [`Debug.Log`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) inside the `OnTriggerEnter` and `Exit`.

Comment: Ok thanks. What do you mean attach script to collider object? I just attatched it to my door. Or by "Collider object" Do you mean the object that has the collider, Sorry if I sound stupid here I'm just a bit paranoid,

Comment: I mean the same gameObject that has the collider. Note that this is probably the same gameObject of the door because of the `GetComponent<Animation>()` which is probably on the door.

Comment: Ah. Also do I need to put a empty game object and attatch it to the door? I was wondering if I could add you on Steam just for a short while so we could figure it out. If not its fine.

Comment: You don't need just an empty gameObject on the door if there would be no behaviours attached to it. If you send me your steam name I'll add you.